# Select2 multiselect search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-select2, multi-select

OK, I'm trying to wrap my head around using Select2, AJAX and Rails to do a multiselect search.  I haven't gotten to the search part yet as I'm trying to get the multiselect part to work first.

My Controller:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to? :html, :JSON

    def index
      @games = Game.order('name').all
      #respond_to @games
    end
end
```

My application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require select2
//= require_tree .
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  placeholder: "Choose a game",
  multiple: true;
  ajax: {
    url: <%= games_path(format: 'json') %>,
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    }
  }
});
```

My games/index.html.erb file

```
Still learning

<select class="#mySelect2"></select>
```

My application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sonar</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :games, only: [:index]
  root to: 'games#index'
end
```

This presents the drop down box, but isn't populating it with the data from the database or presenting a search box to start typing for autocomplete searching.

If I'm understanding it properly, I should have the JS code in the applciation.js file, which is called from the select statement in the index.html file.  The index action in the controller is pulling the data from the database in response to the json request and should then pass the info to the js function.

I do note that I don't have the JS to wait for the page to load before running though, but I tried putting that in the application.js file and it didn't change anything.

*edit - the game table has the ID column, name column and a category ID column.

Comment: Try to this `<select class="mySelect2" multiple></select> ` for your html than call select2 with this `$('.mySelect2').select2()` . you must have values in select2.

Comment: Sorry, the question is more that it's not working.  The select dorpdown box is not populating with the database values and is not providing a search option when you do click on it.

I will try Vishal's suggestion.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I tried your suggestion like this:

<select class="#mySelect2" multiple></select>
<%= $('.myselect2').select2(@games) %>

but it then generates an error for the second line of code (if I don't put the <% %> around it, it just displays as text rather than executes the code)


/home/krefey/dev/sonar/app/views/games/index.html.erb:4: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name /home/krefey/dev/sonar/app/views/games/index.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input eeze;@output_buffer.append=( $('.myselect2').select2(games) ^
Extracted source (around line #4):